# Laravel deployment - Fatal error: Call to a member function make() on string

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to deply laravel app (Laravel 5.4.36), and I uploaded content of the public directory to public_html, and other folders are uploaded in root footer of my hosting username.

Index.php paths are modified to load bootstrap/autoload.php and bootstrap/app.php based on new paths, and I ensured that the index.php has permission to access those files.

The problem is that I get this message when I try to access index.php

```
  Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function make() on string in /home/myuser/public_html/index.php:54 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /home/myuser/public_html/index.php on line 54
```

and the line referred here is

```
$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);
```

I also tried with several php versions, 7.1, 7.2 and 7.3.
I use Apache and Cpanel on shared server, but I also have root access to this server so I can reconfigure what is needed.

I followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6g8G3YQtQt4

Comment: Is there a special reason to change the default directory structure of laravel?

Comment: I can't make the website available via path www.mydomain.com/public, it should be just www.mydomain.com. Public files are inside public_html, and other folders are in the parrent directory.

Comment: For that, it's recommended to change your web server's configuration. What web server do you use?

Comment: I have full access to this web server. It is shared, but I can configure what I want.

Comment: try to follow this link: https://developerhowto.com/2018/11/12/how-to-change-the-laravel-public-folder/

Comment: are you use cpanel ?

Comment: @MohammedZaki changes did not help. Yes I use cpanel, like on the video provided in the question.

Comment: What web server do you use? Apache or nginx

Comment: It is Apache server

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem

The $app was string, I somehow  changed it into string so instead

```
$app =  require_once __DIR__.'/../bel/bootstrap/app.php';
```

it was

```
$app =  __DIR__.'/../bel/bootstrap/app.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

You follow these steps to solve your issue

1. create a new folder for your laravel project.
2. then upload everything in it including public folder without changing paths
3. follow the following steps to change your root folder to /public

https://tecadmin.net/how-to-change-document-root-of-primary-domain-in-cpanel/

For changing the main/primary domain, you will need to have root SSH access and be able to locate and edit the following file (replacing your user & domain info):

/var/cpanel/userdata/USERNAME/DOMAIN.COM
1. Once you have opened the file, look for the following line:

documentroot: /home/USERNAME/public_html
2. Modify the location according to your needs. Save it and exit.

3. Rebuild the Apache conf and restart Apache:

/scripts/rebuildhttpdconf
service httpd restart
The change will be immediate. Simply clear your browser cache and force refresh the page!

or you have another option to just upload your laravel folder beside public_html and all files in laravel public folder in public_html without changing paths